# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, opencv

I have downloaded the following [web-based-face-detect-program](https://github.com/bsdnoobz/web-based-face-detect) and compiled it and my compiler shows no syntax errors, however when I try upload a picture with the application I get a `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined error`. I haven't changed to application at all so there should not be an issue and I am fairly new to Javascript so I could be making a rookie mistake. Heres the js function code:

```
function parse_response(res) {
    var data = jQuery.parseJSON(res);

    if (data.success == false) {
        show_page(form);
        show_message(data.msg);
        return;
    }

    results
        .find(".source-img").html("").end()
        .find(".detected-faces").html("").append("<p>Found " + (data.images.length-1) + " faces:</p>");

    $.each(data.images, function(i, img) {
        var el = '<img src="face-detect/' + img.src + '?r=' + Math.random() + '" alt="" />';
        results.find((i == 0 ? ".source-img" : ".detected-faces")).append(el);
    })

    results.find(".source-img img").bind('click', function(e) {
        var im = data.images[0];
        var el = '<img src="face-detect/' + im.src + '" width="' + im.width + '" height="' + im.height + '" alt="" />';
        $(".lightbox", results).find(".lightbox-content").html(el).end().lightbox("show");
    });

    show_page(results, actions);
}
```

The line `.find(".detected-faces").html("").append("<p>Found " + (data.images.length-1) + " faces:</p>");` is what causes the error. And heres the errors I get in the Chrome console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined app.js:87
parse_response app.js:87
xhr.onreadystatechange app.js:65
```

The rest of the code is all on the github link if theres something I have missed out. So can someone please explain to me why I am getting this undefined error and how I can resolve it?

Comment: It means the response has no "images" property. Use your browser developer console to examine the JSON that's actually returned.

Comment: @Pointy how can I do that? I assumed that was the problem but as it wasn't my code I thought it was in the JSON.

Comment: If you're using Chrome, look in the "Network" tab. You should be able to click on the HTTP transaction that's involved and see the headers and the actual response.

Comment: @Pointy I had a look at the `app.js` transaction and it does have headers and response but neither show me any json output. Have I gone wrong somewhere?

Comment: When you find the HTTP transaction, click on it in the left-side column. You should then be able to click on the "Preview" and "Response" tabs on the top right.  If there's nothing there, that means the server isn't returning anything.

Comment: @Pointy The preview and response only show the js code. So its not empty but it doesnt have anything useful. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the right HTTP transaction? The response should be JSON, not JavaScript.

Comment: @Pointy Ah you may be correct, it appears that in the php file there is some JSON and all it says is `{"success":true}`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the data object have not the images property. Before the error line, use the `JSON.stringify(data)` function to check the data object structure.

You can use:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
```

Or:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(data))
```

Comment: Neither of these show the JSON output to me, with the `alert`is get this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: Alert is not defined ` and the console doesn't show anything either, with the same error.